# Finding an Amazon EC2 hosting instance for a website

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, flash, instance

My company is about to conduct a big project which involves a flash games website. This website is targeted to the US, meaning it will serve a lot of concurrent users. We bought many flash games and the website is about to be finished, so we must find a hosting company right away.

The website consists of 10 static pages, 140KB each (design+images+CSS).
JavaScript is being delivered via Google CDN (jQuery, SWFObject) to save bandwidth.
We have 20 SWF games, each weights around 500KB to 6MB top.

I'm planning to use dynamic compressions and basically any possible method to save bandwidth and resources, but nevertheless I must get a large hosting for possible growing in the future.

SQL is nothing special: DB size will be 150MB top and all tables are indexed using fulltext catalogs and non-clustered indexes.

After doing some research, I've found that big websites are using Amazon's EC2. I tried to contact Amazon but they're weren't really helpful. All I got is the [following URL](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#instance).

I would like you to help me choose the right Amazon instances. We are talking about Windows 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: One more question: do I get a standalone Windows 2008 R2 instance? with remote desktop and everything, like all dedicated servers? if so, does it support scaling? I'm not willing to change my .NET app at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pages are static you should consider hosting them on S3 instead of EC2. See their blog for details http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html.

With S3, you can GZip your content which all modern browsers support. You do have to add the GZip header when uploading to S3. (BTW, this will also allow you to use Cloudfront as a CDN for faster delivery).

Regarding the servers, based on your description a standard small instance should be fine. Small has 1.7 GB of RAM which should be plenty. Is your server hosting the DB and the web app? If so you might need to go with a large instance which includes the SQL licence http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

One thing to note, once you create an instance you cannot change the instance type easily. You can only start, stop, terminate, etc.

Comment: Hi,

Many thanks for you answer.  
Pages are not static, yet SQL queries have minimal work. As for the SQL, I'll need an Amazon one. Are you sure 1.7GB will be enough for the entire US?  
And what about bandwidth? Is there any limit?
(we're willing to pay as much as needed, as long as our website won't freeze)

Comment: There is no limit to bandwidth, you just get charged for what you use. If you are using the Amazon SQL, you will need to get a large instance since Windows+SQL is not offered on a small instance. I am running SQL on an instance in this way with no issues.  You also want to think about redundancy on your SQL box - you still have to consider that the server may go down at some point. You can backup your DB to S3 with this solution http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Backup+%2F+Restore/70242/